# Git repo copied from one location to another, and git pull now reports different counts

Tags: git

I have a git repo that I copied from my disk to an external hard drive through Windows 10 File Explorer.

Then, I opened a git shell in both source and target directory and called "git pull". They should behave the same, but they don't.

Source directory:

```
urban@NBURBAN MINGW64 /t (Master)
$ git pull
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
Counting objects: 79623, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (48167/48167), done.
Writing objects: 100% (79623/79623), done.
Total 79623 (delta 41438), reused 52322 (delta 26522)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
Already up-to-date.
```

Target directory:

```
urban@NBURBAN MINGW64 /d/Backup-20171215 (Master)
$ git pull
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
Counting objects: 79623, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (48167/48167), done.
Writing objects: 100% (79623/79623), done.
Total 79623 (delta 41436), reused 52323 (delta 26522)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking connectivity: 79623, done.
Already up-to-date.
```

Do you notice the small difference in in the "delta" and "reused" count? How can this be, given that both directories should have had the same state to begin with?

Comment: From a straight question-and-answer standpoint, I think torek has the most plausible explanation of *why it happens*. I don't think it applies here, but another thought to the more general "how can this be?" question, some of the detailed diagnostics (where gc is involved) could also change simply because of when the command is run (e.g. bc of reflog expiration).  Which brings me to me real point...

Comment: ... which is it seems to me the more interesting question would be, does it matter (and if so why)? These diagnostics don't really mean much to an end user, and as noted a lot of little factors could change them in seemingly-arbitrary ways. If you just want to validate that the backup is complete and not corrupt, check the hash values of each ref. If they match (and there's no corruption in the repo, as might be detected with a git fsck), then the backup is complete and correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also an added `Checking connectivity:` line.

Consider, though, that you're not running `git gc`, you're running `git pull` which itself runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, usually `git merge`.  All of those are happening more or less simultaneously (well, the two Git commands run by `git pull` are quite sequential, but the background `git gc` runs in parallel with both).

Since the foreground operations—fetching and merging—create Git objects, if there is any slight timing difference between the speed of the background and foreground operations, you can easily have different object counts.  The initial counts all match, so this is probably not the case here, but it's a possibility, so it's worth mentioning.

Meanwhile, the particular objects that `git gc` is allowed to manipulate (including "replace loose objects with packed objects" and "prune away entirely") and items like the order of delta chains are—at least potentially—affected by, among other things, file time stamps.  If you copy a directory full of files, the new files are generally time-stamped "now".<sup>1</sup>  [There is a technical documentation file on pack delta heuristics here.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/52015aaf9d19c97b52c47c7046058e6d029ff856/Documentation/technical/pack-heuristics.txt)  It does not mention file mtimes, but grepping the Git source for `mtime` shows that file-stat mtime fields do enter into some related calculations.

You could try some more carefully-controlled experiments, where you copy the file trees preserving all file metadata, and run `git gc` directly (not `--auto` and without any other Git operations running simultaneously).  I think the observed differences would vanish.

---

<sup>1</sup>I have no idea whether this particular copying method (through Windows 10 File Explorer) preserves time stamps.